# Can a boolean be compared with a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable isRefreshed which is declared in the below manner

```
var isRefreshed ='';
```

and isRefreshed can be assigned a boolean value in some scenario like:

```
isRefreshed=false;
```

now there is a if check to be performed like below

```
if(isRefreshed != '')
{
   // Some action
}
```

the problem is that when a boolean value is assigned to isRefreshed then in that case my condition is satisfied like

`true != ''`

is returning true which is not desired. So my question is can we compare a boolean with a string in jquery.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly's answer below should work for your immediate predicament, but the real answer here is: don't do that.  If you have a boolean, initialize it as such: `var isRefreshed = false;`

Comment: @musefan Yeah yoy are right mine condition was true not false , i have edited my question

Comment: Here is a [very cool video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook#t=875) about stuff like this by Douglas Crockford everyone writing javascript should have seen this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `!==` to compare type as well as content.

```
false != ''  // false - both false and '' are falsy values
false !== '' // true - Boolean isn't equal to string type
```

Further reading: [*falsy* values](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/), [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

In your situation, however, you could get away with just using:

```
if (isRefreshed) { ... }
```

This is equal to `if (isRefreshed == true)`, but as mentioned above both `false` and `''` are *falsy* values and will evaluate to false.

Comment: To expand on this, in `isRefreshed !== ''` the condition needs it to NOT be an empty string. In `isRefreshed !== false` the condition needs it to NOT be a boolean with the value "false".